# Picking up redirect parameters

Tags: java, servlets, redirect, http-redirect

When sending a redirect is it possible to see what are the parameters passed from the servlet we redirected to?

For exampe:

We redirect from servlet servletA

```
   protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException {
       resp.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath()+"/foo#fooMethod:val1="+val1+"&val2="+val2);
   }
```

So what does servlet servletB need to do to pick up val1/val2/fooMethod?

```
protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException { 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As just like your query parameters.

```
String value2 = req.getParameter("val2");
```

And same goes for remaining  too.

And I belive you need to write `?` instead of `#` to append the query parameters to the url.

Answer (score 0):

See the reference on Sun/Oracle's java servlet site:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html

You'd essentially have to do `req.getParameter("val2")`
will be a String Type and you can convert it to whatever type you need.

In the future if your parameter has more than one value you'd use `getParameterValues(java.lang.String)`. You can pass arrays of Strings, etc.

Also 
`/foo#fooMethod:val1=` should be

```
/foo?doGet:val1=yourValue&val2=yourNextValue&val3=yourNextNextValue
```